# Very slow ubuntu 12.04 server. Seems to have plenty of resources

Tags: ubuntu, performance, ubuntu-12.04

I am experiencing slow page loads and slow SSH responsiveness, but when I run `htop` I appear to have plenty (1gb+) of available memory and the CPU seems to be pretty chilled.

Is there a better way to find where the bottle neck is?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe You can try `iostat 1` and see what's going on with Your disks. (If it says that it's not installed, You can install it with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install sysstat`)

Also You can set "Detailed CPU time" option at hTop's Display Options (jump to there with F2), and see if any iowait is there (it will show up at as grey CPU usage (like system is red, user green and so on)

Or simply use `top` and see the wa field:

> %Cpu(s): 11,9 us,  5,3 sy,  0,2 ni, 82,6 id,  **0,0 wa**,  0,0 hi, 
>   0,0 si,  0,0 st

And, finally if it's a remote station maybe it's a good idea to check latency with for example ping.